# Firebase cloud messaging not working in doze mode even with high priority

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-doze, doze

I am doing a e-hailing project. User will be placing order and driver will be receiving a notification when user placed an order.
For iOS, everything work fine. Notification can be received by driver without any issue when there is a new order for driver to grab.
However, for android device, notification will not be received by driver when the device is screen off after few minutes. This is something to deal with the doze mode i guess. But i have try to use foreground service and set the priority as "high". But problem still exists.
Android device only will be working without any issue when the device is charging or screen on or interacting with the mobile device.
Can anyone help me with this? Notification really important as to notify the driver to grab the order at timely manner

I have set the message priority to "High" and create a foreground service.